# Sqlite database fails on target due to 'long long int' (64 bits) data type

Tags: c, sqlite, embedded

I'm working on an embedded project that uses Sqlite to store/retrieve data.

SQLITE_INT64_TYPE is defined as long long int (default definition).

When reading the database schema, the root page number is wrongly interpreted.

When the schema is read, the root page numbers for the tables are word-order interchanged. For example, root page number '**2**' is read as '**8589934592**' (0x0200000000).

Because of this any other SQL statements given to the database do not return any results.

Target description:

- Platform: Armv7
- Compiler: GCC
- Arch type: little-endian

Any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Thanks

PS: Modified the original post after identifying the root cause now.

```c
#include "sqlite3.h"


int sqlite3_port_exec_callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   printf("%s: ", (const char*)data);
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc, i, ncols;
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *sql;
    const char *tail;
    char *look_aside_buf;


    rc = sqlite3_open("USB1:\\foods.db", &db);
    if(rc) {
        printf( "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }



    const char* data = "Callback function called";
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    sql = "SELECT * from sqlite_master";


    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, &sqlite3_port_exec_callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        printf( "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
        printf( "Operation done successfully\n");
    }


    zErrMsg = 0;
    /* Create SQL statement */
    sql = "SELECT * from episodes";


    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, &sqlite3_port_exec_callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        printf( "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
        printf( "Operation done successfully\n");
    }




    zErrMsg = 0;
    /* Create SQL statement */
    sql = "SELECT count(*) from episodes";
    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, &sqlite3_port_exec_callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
        printf( "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
        printf( "Operation done successfully\n");
    }


    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Output as follows:

```
Callback function called: type = table
name = episodes
tbl_name = episodes
rootpage = 8589934592
sql = CREATE TABLE episodes (
  id integer primary key,
  season int,
  name text )

Callback function called: type = table
name = foods
tbl_name = foods
rootpage = 30064771072
sql = CREATE TABLE foods(
  id integer primary key,
  type_id integer,
  name text )

Callback function called: type = table
name = foods_episodes
tbl_name = foods_episodes
rootpage = 77309411328
sql = CREATE TABLE foods_episodes(
  food_id integer,
  episode_id integer )

Callback function called: type = table
name = food_types
tbl_name = food_types
rootpage = 107374182400
sql = CREATE TABLE food_types(
  id integer primary key,
  name text )

Operation done successfully
Operation done successfully
Callback function called: count(*) = 0

Operation done successfully
```

Comment: Same version of sqlite on both sides? Do you copy the database file from the PC to your embedded device or do you create it from scratch on the embedded device? Did you try with a more simple database?

Comment: + Are you reading the database directly from your embedded system's memory?

Comment: I keep a copy of the database in a removable device for the system to access.  The database file was created in the PC.

Comment: Sqlite version used is same on PC and the target.  The database was created using Sqlite's command line tool on PC and then opened on the target from a USB device.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Post has been modified after identifying the root cause. Pls have a look.

Comment: @user2553780: Post has been modified. Pls have a look at it.

Comment: Your output does not match the test program; where is the code that prints "rootpage = " for example?

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause and wanted to bring this thread to a close.

Well this is really embarrassing!  There were 2 copies of the 'Sqlite.h' header files within the project and each of them had different configuration for SQLITE_INT64_TYPE.  Hence the difference in the output.

Many thanks to all people who have spent time on this.